# Are there any official movies, novels or short stories set in the same universe as Event Horizon?

Tags: event-horizon

[Event Horizon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119081/) has always been a favorite movie of mine.

Do we know if there are any official / canon movies, novels, short stories or animations set in the Event Horizon universe?

Comment: warhammer 40k  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The film spawned an [Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2843398-event-horizon) which, for the record, wasn't any better than the film.

As far as I can tell, no other official media came out of the film other than a feature-length "[Making Of](https://youtu.be/kxQJhkozHrs)" documentary.

---

You may also want to have a look at some (cut) images that were leaked a few years ago.

Warning. [NSFW - Gory](http://WWW.imgur.com/a/xUUcw)

Comment: I didn't think they could get much more gory than the vivisection, but it seems I may have been mistaken

Comment: @Raystafarian - Allegedly the final edit was some 20 minutes shorter than the initial edit.

Comment: Geez, that's lucky, I accidentally watched that when I was 12 - I was interested in space and black holes and thought it would be science fiction - only. It haunts me.

Comment: @Raystafarian I had the same reaction at 30.